# Type error: Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: typescript, next.js, build, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I am working on a next js project, and to wrap the providers I have used a function as follows:

```js
"use client";

import React, { ComponentProps, FC, ReactNode } from "react";

export const combineComponents = (...components: FC[]): FC => {
  return components.reduce(
    (AccumulatedComponents, CurrentComponent) => {
      return ({ children }: { children?: ReactNode }): JSX.Element => {
        return (
          <AccumulatedComponents>
            <CurrentComponent {...(children && { children })} />
          </AccumulatedComponents>
        );
      };
    },
    ({ children }) => <>{children}</>
  );
};
```

This function is used as follows:

```js
"use location";

import { UserProvider } from "@/providers/user";
import { LocationProvider } from "@/providers/location";
import { combineComponents } from "@/utils/combineComponents";

interface LocationProviderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

interface UserProviderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const providers = [LocationProvider, UserProvider];

export const AppContextProvider = combineComponents(...providers);
```

The application runs well on the development server. But it is unable to build.

During build, I get an error message saying:

```
npm run build

> myapplication@0.1.0 build
> next build

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.3

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully

./utils/combineComponents.tsx:10:12
Type error: Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

   8 |       return ({ children }: { children?: ReactNode }): JSX.Element => {
   9 |         return (
> 10 |           <AccumulatedComponents>
     |            ^
  11 |             <CurrentComponent {...(children && { children })} />
  12 |           </AccumulatedComponents>
  13 |         );
```